# Why would a printer print wrong colors only from some apps?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, pdf, printing, printer

I have an F2200 printer with 2 cartridges - B&W and Tri-Color which I'm using with a Windows 10 computer using their supplied "[driver](http://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/swdetails/hp-deskjet-f2200-all-in-one-printer-series/3390944/swItemId/al-109215-2)"  .
When printing something like an image - it prints fine, including the color blue. But when printing from MS Word or Adobe Acrobat Reader - blue text is printed as pink.

When I go to the printer properties in device manager, there's no "driver" tab.

This printer used to work fine with Windows 7. And the printer tells me there's more than half of the ink left in the color cartridge.

Any idea what can be the cause of that?

Comment: What are the apps that print correctly? Does a printer test page show all jets are working?

Comment: Blue is printed with primarily cyan & magenta inks, pink with primarily magenta & yellow inks.  So if there was a problem with cyan (clogged nozzles or empty ink color), blue could show up as pink.  However, that should affect any printing.  If it's happening with only certain apps, that would suggest something flaky in what the app is sending to the printer.  One simple test would be to load one of the free third-party PDF drivers (where you select that program as if it's a printer and it saves the output to a PDF).  Use that with the problem apps and see what the resulting PDF looks like.